# How do I get rid of this specific Error 9 on Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code. I try to run it and it keeps popping this error, even if before it was working properly. The only thing I added was the very last thing with the worksheets.

Oh and apart from this, how can i make it run when one specific sheet is opened. I am asking that because whenever I save my file on another sheet and then reopen the file, it shows a normal error because I am on a different sheet that I am supposed to.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim j As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer, result As String, temp As Long, answer As Integer, myValue1 As Integer, l As Integer, Number As Integer, Number1 As Integer
If Cells(3, 2) = Cells(3, 8) Then
result = "fail"
j = 2
Do While result = "fail" And Cells(9, j) <> ""
    If Cells(9, j).Value >= 15 Then
        result = "pass"
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If
Loop
If result = "fail" Then
      answer = MsgBox("Do you want to add more weeks?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question To User")
      If answer = vbYes Then
         myValue1 = InputBox("How many more weeks do you want to bulk?")
         For i = 7 To 13
              Cells(i, j - 1).Select
              Selection.Copy
              Cells(i, 100).Select
              Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
              Cells(i, j - 1) = " "
         Next i
         For i = 15 To 15 + Cells(2, 8)
             Cells(i, j - 1).Select
             Selection.Copy
             Cells(i, 100).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
             SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             Cells(i, j - 1) = " "
         Next i
         For i = 17 + Cells(2, 8) To 26 + Cells(2, 8)
             Cells(i, j - 1).Select
             Selection.Copy
             Cells(i, 100).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
             SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             Cells(i, j - 1) = " "
         Next i
         For i = j - 1 To j + myValue1 - 2
            Cells(7, i) = "Week" & " " & i - 1
            Cells(7, i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            With Selection.Font
                .Color = -4165632
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Cells(15, i) = "Week" & " " & i - 1
            Cells(15, i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            With Selection.Font
                .Color = -4165632
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Cells(17 + Cells(2, 8), i) = "Week" & " " & i - 1
            Cells(17 + Cells(2, 8), i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            With Selection.Font
                .Color = -4165632
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
         Next i
         For j = 7 To 13
            Cells(j, 100).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(j, i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(j, 100) = " "
            If j = 7 Then
                Cells(j, i).Select
                With Selection.Font
                    .Color = -16776961
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
         Next j
         For j = 15 To 15 + Cells(2, 8)
            Cells(j, 100).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(j, i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(j, 100) = " "
            If j = 15 Then
                Cells(j, i).Select
                With Selection.Font
                    .Color = -16776961
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next j
        For j = 17 + Cells(2, 8) To 26 + Cells(2, 8)
            Cells(j, 100).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(j, i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(j, 100) = " "
            If j = 17 + Cells(2, 8) Then
                Cells(j, i).Select
                With Selection.Font
                  .Color = -16776961
                  .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next j
        Number = i
        Cells(3, 8) = myValue1 - 2
 Else
    'do nothing
End If
Else
  MsgBox "It is generally advised for men to stay under 15% Body-Fat when trying to gain muscle. So please move to the next Cut Sheet to start losing fat."
k = j
Do While Cells(8, k) <> ""
    k = k + 1
Loop
For i = 8 To 13
    For l = j To k - 2
        Cells(i, l) = " "
    Next l
Next i
For i = 8 To 13
    Cells(i, j) = Cells(i, k - 1)
    Cells(i, k - 1) = " "
Next i
Number = k - 1
Cells(3, 8) = k - 2
End If
For i = 1 To Number
    Columns(i).Select
    Columns(i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next i
End If
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B4") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 8))
End Sub
```

Comment: Error 9 is *"Subscript out of range"*. First identify the line where that error occurs, then check the names of your Worksheets.

Comment: How do I identify the line? Do I simply run the loops and stuff separately by copy/pasting it elsewhere?

Comment: Use `F8` to run through your code line by line. Also it probably should be `.Value` in your added line like `Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 8).Value).Value`. And also get rid off the `.Select` and adress the cells directly.

Comment: also `.Cells(3,8).Value` is not allowed to be <1. Thats what happened a few times to me. But i always got `Error 1004` and not `Error 9`.

Answer (score 0):

When working with specific references to workbooks and worksheets, you should call out the current target specifically.  (if I'm fully understanding your inquiry)

```
'active target
Dim objWB As Workbook: Set objWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim objWS As Worksheet: Set objWS = objWB.ActiveSheet

objWS.Cells(...
objWS.Range(...
```

If you have multiple Excel Workbooks open, code will sometimes run against the focused target, regardless of where the code is running.

**edit*additionally**
Naming your worksheets and referencing them at the beginning of the procedure call will also remove the error of focus code issues.

Dim objWS As Worksheet: Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets("MyWorksheet")